# Can't build a project with Chilkat library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10, chilkat, ios12

Can't build a project with Chilkat library in Xcode10, compilation fails with error:

> library not found for -lstdc++.6

Apple Forum shows:

> libstdc++ was deprecated about 5 years ago (note that it hasn't been
>   available in tvOS nor watchOS).  Please switch to using libc++.

Any ideas on how to migrate the project to iOS12 and Xcode10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libstdc++ was deprecated, the support was removed from the iOS 12 simulator (not for device), now you must use libc++ instead.

Your version of Chilkat library was built with libstdc++, [here](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ios.asp) you can find an updated version built with libc++.

Replace the library with the new one and rebuild.

Comment: The direct link to the versioned Chilkat download may not work in the future. Best to go to the downloads web page at https://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ios.asp

Comment: Thanks, Kerberos and Cesare! It compiles now.

Comment: Thanks to Matt, I've changed the link to the download page.